# how to loop over group shapes without selection them multiple times

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to loop over 12 shapes, all with a group of a picture and a textbox.
The code seems to be correct, but it does not work.
Word/VBA is selecting the shapes multiple times and with a different order each time:

```
Dim sh As Shape

Dim i As Integer
Dim li As Integer
i = 0
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
For Each sh In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    Debug.Print "ID " + CStr(sh.ID)
    i = i + 1

    If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
        sh.Name = "Group " + CStr(i)
        sh.Select
        For li = 1 To sh.GroupItems.Count
            If sh.GroupItems(li).Type = msoTextBox Then
                sh.GroupItems(li).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

The multiple selection can be viewd using the `sh.select`

The output the ID for two runs it the following:

```
12 
ID 4
ID 13
ID 3
ID 22
ID 31
ID 19
ID 4
ID 3
ID 31
ID 4
ID 31
ID 31
12 
ID 25
ID 28
ID 16
ID 13
ID 19
ID 4
ID 25
ID 16
ID 19
ID 25
ID 19
ID 19
```

Comment: This code works fine for me in Word 2013.

Comment: I am using Office 365. I reduced it to 3 groups (deleted the others). It selects them as 7; 4;  4. The third one is never selected.

Comment: Have you tried this in a fresh document?